# What is the meaning/grammar behind noun + でいる?

Tags: meaning, particle-で

I've come across phrases like this a couple of times where でいる is used right after a noun instead of the usual Te-form verb + いる:

> どうせ学生**でいる**なら一番でいたいし

In this case is it basically just the same as である?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

いる means to stay and で いる means to remain something or to keep being something.

It's different from である in the point that でいる implies that one is in that state for a certain period of time and no longer so when it's expired.