# Why である instead of でいる？

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particles, particle-で, daily-life

One solution that I heard is aru can be used for people you're not close to and iru for people you are close to, so like a humble thing, but, I don't know if it's actually said, and aru is for unliving things, but is this really into depth, and I just didn't get into depth? By the way, this isn't a clone, because all the things I have searched up are dumbed down into one meaning but no explanation really... To stay, to keep, but why aru isn't?

Comment: Are you asking about `～がある vs ～がいる`, or `～である vs ～でいる`? They are different topics.

Comment: care to provide example sentences? Not much to go off of here.

Comment: @andrewb please try to be more specific with your question. For starters, you question lacks a verb. Why *what* ?

Comment: @jarmanso7 did you mean to tag OP and tagged me instead? :)

Comment: okay so for example, 人が幸せ(a random adjective)です, i thought aru was supposed to be for non living things, and apparently 人が幸せでいる is different?

Comment: @andrewb, my bad, I meant to tag OP. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comment section, you must see the particle before ある/いる. "ある is for inanimate things and いる is for animate things" is a rule that is relevant when ある/いる is used as an existence verb. This rule has nothing to do with the usage of **で**ある and **で**いる because these constructions do not express the existence of something/someone in the first place.

Basically ～である is a stilted copula, i.e., a literary version of ～だ. ～でいる is a copula in progressive aspect, i.e., "to stay/keep X" in English. See: [What is the difference between でいる and である in this example?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66270/5010) / [What is the meaning/grammar behind noun + でいる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62732/5010)

Here is a very simple summary:

- X**が**いる。
  There is X.
  <sub>(X is a person, animal, etc.)</sub>
- X**が**ある。
  There is X.
  <sub>(X is an inanimate object.)</sub>
- A**は**X**で**ある。
  A is X. (literary/formal)
  <sub>(X is a noun, a na-adjective or a no-adjective)</sub>
- A**は**X**で**いる。
  A stays X. / A keeps being X.
  <sub>(X is a noun, a na-adjective or a no-adjective)</sub>

And simplest examples:

- 猫**が**いる。
  There is a cat.
  <sub>(猫 is an animal)</sub>
- 本**が**ある。
  There is a book.
  <sub>(本 is an inanimate object)</sub>
- 私**は**学生**で**ある。
  I am a student.
  <sub>(である is a stilted だ)</sub>
- 私**は**元気**で**いる。
  I am keeping healthy. / I'm doing well.

Comment: Does でいる have the same stilted feel as である?